# Javascript function is not getting call from code behind when it is put on master page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have 2 pages named as :**Abc.aspx and popupAbc.aspx**

Now on **Abc.aspx** i have below button on click of which i am opening **popupAbc.aspx** as pop up:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOpenChildAbcPopup" runat="server" Text="Open" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnOpenChildAbcPopup_Click" />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void btnOpenChildAbcPopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url="../popupAbc.aspx";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "alert", "OpenChildAbcPopup('" + url + "');",
                    true);
        }

function OpenChildAbcPopup(url) {
                    $.fancybox({
                        'onStart ': function () { $.fancybox.hideActivit() },
                        'onComplete': function () { $.fancybox.hideActivity() },
                        'titleShow': 'true',
                        'titlePosition': 'over',
                        'titleFormat': 'formatTitle',
                        'href': url,//popupAbc.aspx
                        'type': 'iframe',
                        'width': '1000',
                        'height': '500',
                        'fitToView': false,
                        'autoSize': false,
                        'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
                        'hideOnContentClick': false,
                        'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
                        'enableEscapeButton': false,
                        'closeEffect': 'none' 
                    });
                    $.fancybox.hideLoading();
                    return false;
                }
```

Here up till now everythings works perfectly and on click of button my `popupAbc.aspx` opens perfectly in pop up box but problem is with in this `popupAbc.aspx`.

i have one  button in `popupAbc.aspx` in which i will save some data and after saving data i would like to again call the
javascript function which is on master page but that javascript function is not calling.

This is my page:**popupAbc.aspx**

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/MyMaster.Master" CodeBehind="popupAbc.aspx.cs" Inherits="popupAbc.aspx" %>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="true"  ValidationGroup="p1" />

 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //code for saving form data in database and after that call javascript function which
            //is on MyMaster page
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "Js", "ExitMyCurrentFancyBox();", true);
        }
```

But in firebug console it is throwing **error** that **ExitMyCurrentFancyBox is not defined**.

When i put this **ExitMyCurrentFancyBox** function in my `popupAbc.aspx` then it is calling successfully but when i put this on my master page then it is not calling.

```
function ExitMyCurrentFancyBox() {
                alert()
            }
```

**Note**:**My Abc.aspx** uses `update panel` and **popupAbc.aspx** doesnt uses `update panel`.

Can anybody tell me why that Javascript function is not calling when i put it on master page and how to call it when it is on master page??

I have tried all this but still any of below is not working:

```
 // ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "alert", "ExitMyCurrentFancyBox();", true);
               // ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "alert", "ExitMyCurrentFancyBox();", true);
                //ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "sas", "CloseFancyboxtl();", true);
              //  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ntmtch", "ExitMyCurrentFancyBox();", true);
          //  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "msg", "ExitMyCurrentFancyBox();", true);
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "msg", "ExitMyCurrentFancyBox;", true);
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "ExitMyCurrentFancyBox();", true);
```

Comment: because it is not public method. You may create some public method, which executes your javascript code, and call that method from your child page instead

Comment: Thanks for the reply but can you please show how to do it.can you please post some solution

Answer (score 1):

Posting possible solution due to your request.

Add next method to your MasterPage:

```
public void ShowMyJavascript(){
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Here is my message to be displayed as an alert');</script>");
}
```

And in your content page:

```
this.Master.ShowMyJavascript();
```

Comment: i just want to call my ExitMyCurrentFancyBox js function instead of writing script

Comment: @Learning I've found how to fix your code. Change your register to: *ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "js", "ExitMyCurrentFancyBox()", true);* and it will work. Also check that your javascript is inside the head tag of master page, inside <script> tags. and also check the syntax to make sure

Comment: after using this:ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "js", "ExitMyCurrentFancyBox()", true);I am getting this error in my firebug console:SyntaxError: missing ; before statement.I am just firing alert in my js function and i have referenced all the js in head tag

Comment: write here your javascript function please